# When the number of parameters of a method could be considered too many

Tags: oop, parameters

Question (1) Is there a number that we could consider as being too many regarding the number of parameters of a certain method?

It just seems weird to have methods with 30 parameters or more. I would guess that probably results from a bad design in the first place.

Question (2) What would be a good strategy to overcome this problem? Creating objects to encapsulate all the parameters seems to be one option, but is there any other short-term measures to overcome this problem?

Ps. In this example the programming language would be vb.net, or c# or even java.

Comment: It depends in the language you are using. Because in for example php there are a lot of global native functions meaning it would result in less params being injected than other languages. When having too many argument for a method you are likely violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and/or other [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: @PeeHaa I agree to your comment. In this example the programming language would be vb.net, or c# or even java.

Comment: Look in Clean Code, there is a chapter dedicated to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already observed, a set of parameters can be wrapped up as an object, so at one level of abstraction every attribute of an object is a "parameter". In real applications we might well pass quite complex objects such as Customers, Orders, Vehicles etc to a function, and hence could be seen as passing hundreds of attributes, effectively hundreds of parameters.

So I don't think that we can really appeal to SRP or SOLID to guide us as to the number of pieces of data being passed. If we need to pass a Customer and a Customer has lots of attributes then so be it.

But I think the case you're really asking about is where we seem to be adding more and more separate parameters and life gets difficult for the person writing the call, and for the maintainer. Now was it parameter 7 that controls the buffer size and parameter 8 that determines the timeout ...?

Of course there cannot be any absolute maximum but my rule of thumb is 5, above that we have a potential issue. Your suggestion of grouping the parameters into objects is the obvious solution, and when some parameters are optional can really help the caller. An example might be an "communication options" object that has things like buffer sizes, timeouts and retry limits. When the parameters don't naturally coalesce into such objects I think it's a sign that something is not right.

Comment: I guess you got my question right. So we can conclude that the problem is not really the number of parameters, but how encapsulated they are right? If the number of arguments is growing bigger, maybe it is time to encapsulate some of these in order to avoid confusion and increase maintainability. Tks!